How to Create a Token Using Django REST Framework?
I am trying to implement token-based authentication in my Django project using Django REST Framework, but I am unsure of the steps required to create and manage tokens.
I Installed Django REST Framework and djangorestframework-authtoken:

Used the command pip install djangorestframework djangorestframework-authtoken.
Configured settings.py:

Added settings.py : rest_framework and rest_framework.authtoken to INSTALLED_APPS.
Added token authentication to DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES.
Created and registered token views:

Attempted to use built-in views such as ObtainAuthToken for token creation.
Attempted to configure URL routing:

Added URL patterns for token endpoints.
I expected to be able to generate a token when a user logs in and use that token for subsequent authenticated requests. I am unsure if I have set up the views and URL configurations correctly.


Could someone provide a clear explanation on how to properly set up token creation and authentication with Django REST Framework?
